# O que significa a expressão "convencido de ignorante por alguém"?

Tags: verbos, significado-em-contexto, regência

Estava lendo as confissões de Santo Agostinho (editora petra, tradução de Frederico Ozanam Pessoa de Barro, p.124 do primeiro volume), quando me deparo com o seguinte texto:

> Por isso Manés, afastando-se dessa regra, falou tanto sobre essas coisas, que, convencido de ignorante pelos que as conhecem bem, viu-se claramente o crédito que merecia em matérias mais obscuras.

Contexto:

- Manés é o profeta criador do maniqueísmo.
- As "coisas" se referem aos assuntos e discussões trazidas pelo profeta que, no entender do santo, não são proveitosas, por isso as classifica "como matérias obscuras".

Não entendi o que significa o predicativo(?) "convencido de ignorante pelos que as conhecem bem"

Comment: A minha interpretação de "essas coisas" é diferente. Creio que elas se referem a coisas terrenas (como previsão de eclipses), que não são necessárias à piedade (sentimento religioso). As "matérias mais obscuras" são, na minha opinião, outras matérias, diferentes das terrenas; se são "mais" obscuras, têm de ser outras. Numa tradução em inglês vem "abstruser", ou ’mais difíceis’, em vez de "mais obscuras".

Comment: Se "ignorante" se refere a "Manés" então, interpreto como "convencido de que é ignorante" ou "convencido da (sua) ignorância". Se assim for, "convencido de ignorante pelos que as conhecem bem" diria que Manés foi convencido de que é ignorante pelos que "as conhecem bem".

Comment: Hellofriends, podes incluir a referência das tuas *Confissões* na pergunta (editora, ano, nome do tradutor, página). Isto é boa prática em geral quando se inclui uma citação, e seria especialmente útil (pelo menos para mim) neste caso. Eu suspeito que isto seja uma tradução antiga, ou adaptação de tradução antiga, o que explicaria a aceção arcaica de *convencido*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *Fulano foi convencido* = ’foi provado que fulano é culpado’

***Convencido de ignorante*** é no mínimo muito incomum e um arcaísmo. Poderá ter sido influência desta [tradução espanhola de 1930](https://www.augustinus.it/spagnolo/confessioni/conf_05.htm), que usa precisamente essas palavras; este tipo de construção parece ser comum no espanhol.

Mas em português, do que vi nos dicionários e literatura, o normal seria ***convencido de ignorância*** ou ***convencido de ser ignorante***. Mas isto induziria em erro o leitor atual: qualquer um pensaria que o Manés ficou persuadido de que era ignorante. Mas nas *Confissões* o verbo *convencer* é usado no sentido do inglês *convict*, sentido que caiu em desuso entre nós e que só se encontra em dicionários antigos, como no [Raphael Bluteau (1712)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=18VKAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA522&lpg=RA1-PA522&dq=%22Convencer%20a%20alguem.%20Aliquem%22&source=bl&ots=57cQjUXOX_&sig=ACfU3U0y-AFB4fokPCbO5pFZOnIyN34DKw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi80_vn9r_yAhVQOBoKHdNqCgAQ6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Convencer%20a%20alguem.%20Aliquem%22&f=false), [Domingos Vieira (1873)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=sWzh2uSTUQUC&pg=PA492&dq=%22Provar%20contra%20alguem%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDhf329cTyAhWPAGMBHRuXA44Q6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Provar%20contra%20alguem%22&f=false) ou no verbete original do [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/convencer):

> […] **Convencer de** 1. provar que é culpado de: O juiz *convenceu-o de* furto.

Então o que a passagem diz é que os que conhecem bem aquelas coisas provaram que o Manés era “culpado de ignorância”.

Encontra-se esta uso de *convencer* na literatura e imprensa do passado; a tentação de interpretar *convencido* como ’persuadido’ pode ser muito forte, mas clicando e lendo o contexto, verão que o significado é ’provado que é culpado’: [“convencido de adultério”](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=234788&pesq=%22convencido%20de%20adulterio%22&pasta=ano%20187&pagfis=9282) (*Gazeta Jurídica*, Rio de Janeiro, 1877), [“homens convencidos de indiscrição”](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Quincas_Borba/XXXII) (Machado de Assis, 1891); [“convencido de um momento de infidelidade”](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/O_mo%C3%A7o_loiro/XXXIII) (Joaquim Manuel de Macedo, 1845); e encontramos esta linguagem numa lei ainda em vigor no estado de São Paulo (obrigado ao Loremlpsum, que ma trouxe à atenção), que pune com demissão o funcionário que [“for convencido de incontinência pública e escandalosa”](https://www.al.sp.gov.br/repositorio/legislacao/lei/1968/lei-10261-28.10.1968.html).

### Interpretação das *Confissões*

Podemos confirmar que é esta a interpretação correta de *convencido* olhando o [original em latim lado a lado com uma tradução em inglês de 1631](https://archive.org/details/staugustinesconf01augu/page/218/mode/2up?q=%22convictus%20ab%20eis%22):

> […] **convictus** ab eis, que ista vere didicissent
>
> […] **confuted** by those who had learned the truth of these things

Ora [confute somebody (Oxford Learners Dictionary)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/confute?q=confute) significa ’provar que esse alguém está errado’. E o *convictus* do latim original é o particípio passado de *convincere*, que segundo o [Etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=convict) entre outras coisas significava “convict of crime or error”, ou ’dar por provado que cometeu crime ou erro’. ; o [dicionário de latim de Lewis e Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=convinco) acrescenta “refute”, que partilha o significado de ’refutar’, entre outros,  ’anular afirmações ou julgamentos de outrem de maneira categórica’ ([Michaelis 4](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/refutar/)). Então em português, e para evitar a confusão do arcaísmo *convencer*, poderíamos dizer:

> Manés […] falou tanto dessas coisas, que, **provada a sua ignorância** pelos que as conhecem bem […]

ou simplesmente

> Manés […] falou tanto dessas coisas, que, **refutado** pelos que as conhecem bem […]

Isto faz sentido no contexto geral. Começando no livro V, capítulo III (têm aqui [esta tradução em português](https://img.cancaonova.com/noticias/pdf/277537_SantoAgostinho-Confissoes.pdf); não consegui encontrar a citada na pergunta), Santo Agostinho diz que comparou os ensinamentos de Manés sobre coisas terrenas (movimentos dos astros, eclipses e coisas assim) com os dos antigos filósofos, e concluiu que Manés está errado. Então é isto que ele quer dizer com “convictus” ou refutado pelos que as conhecem bem [essas coisas]”: os antigos filósofos (na verdade, os seus ensinamentos) provaram que Manés estava errado. E se ele estava errado acerca de coisas terrenas quanto mais não estaria acerca de coisas mais complexas, divinas. Note-se que não há nas *Confissões* qualquer sugestão que o Manés tenha reconhecido os seus erros, ou que ele tenha sequer dado atenção aos ensinamentos dos filósofos. Logo o sentido que nos é familiar de *convencer* (’persuadir’) não se aplica ali.

Comment: perfeito! A resposta mais completa que eu poderia querer. Obrigado.

Comment: @hellofriends, ah... és muito gentil e pouco ambicioso :) Fico contente que tenhas gostado.

Comment: @hellofriends, fiz algumas alterações: expliquei melhor o contexto daquele trecho; reforcei uns pontos aqui e ali, e inclinei-me agora mais para *convencer de* implicar não só que ficou provado que a pessoa fez algo, mas também que a pessoa reconhece isso; é que vários dicionários antigos sugerem isso.

Comment: @LoremIpsum, esse exemplo é excelente! O primeiro natural, fora de um dicionário, que eu vejo. Então vejo com melhores olhos o "convencido de ignorância": no Estatuto deve ser irrelevante se o funcionário "convencido" admite ou não a sua culpa. Mas a verdade é que não temos nenhuma outra palavra para esse sentido de "convencido": temos de dizer "declarado culpado, julgado culpado em tribunal" ou coisa assim. Arcaísmo: aquilo são possivelmente traduções antigas, ou adaptações de traduções antigas; a que eu linkei foi publicada por uma organização religiosa, sem nome de tradutor nem nada.

Comment: Interessante, Jacinto. Eu jamais teria pensado nisso, já que *convencido de ignorante* não me parece estranho — um pouco diferente, mas não estranho. Parabéns pela resposta!

Comment: @Schilive, O "convencido de ignorante" versus "... de ignorância" é uma questão relativamente menor. Ao que parece, "... de ignorante" é ou foi usado em espanhol, e eu tou em crer que aquela tradução portuguesa foi adaptada de uma espanhola praticamente "igual" que eu encontrei; em português encontrei um único exemplo de "convencido de ignorante", do Rio Grande do Sul. Coincidência? Agora o choque para mim foi descobrir que "convencer de ignorância" significava "provar que é culpado de ignorância" (= ao "convict" do inglês)!